# how to add value into database taken from input alert dialog box

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-database

Its a game in which at the end activity the score is displayed But before that the input alert box is displayed where user need to add their name,and that name and score should go to the database. score is getting stored but not the name. how to get name from input alert dialog box and set it on db.insertScore(Score,Name). Even declare Name as global it still not working
here is my code

```
  Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra != null)
    {
        showInputDialog();
        final int Score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
        final int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
        int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");
        txtTotalScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", Score));
        txtTotalQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d/%d", correctAnswer, totalQuestion));

        progressBarResult.setMax(totalQuestion);
        progressBarResult.setProgress(correctAnswer);

        //save score
       db.insertScore(Score,Name);
    }
}


protected void showInputDialog() {

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Done.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Done.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String Name = editText.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not being added is because you define the `Name` variable in the dialog box, which limits the scope of your variable to that condition. If I were you, I would create a class variable, called `name`, then create a getter and setter for the variable. Then inside your dialog box, you could call `setName(name)`. Then when you store the data in your database, you can call `db.insertScore(Score,getName());`. Also, FWIW, variables should be lowercase. Uppercase is typically reserved for class names.

Comment: i already have getter and setter i had call setName(name) its say cannot resolve

Comment: @PurshottamGusain Post the code, but that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 more function to store the score and edited name into database. Follow the code below.

```
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra != null)
    {
        final int Score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
        final int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
        int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");
        txtTotalScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", Score));
        txtTotalQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d/%d", correctAnswer, totalQuestion));

        progressBarResult.setMax(totalQuestion);
        progressBarResult.setProgress(correctAnswer);



        //show dialog
        showInputDialog(Score);
    }


    protected void showInputDialog(final int score) {

        // get prompts.xml view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Done.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Done.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        String Name = editText.getText().toString();

                        storeData(Name, score);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    protected void storeData(String name, final int score){
        db.insertScore(score,name);
    }
```

Comment: It has stop working. when the page reaches at this activity it stopped